# TypeError: '_SentinelObject' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, django-3.2

I am upgrading my Django application from version ***2.2*** to ***3.2***. while upgrading i am facing below issue, i have spent a lot of time to resolve this but didn't get any solution yet.

here's the traceback of issue which i am facing:

```
  File ".../abc/test.py", line 85, in setUp
    self.MODEL_A.save()
  File ".../abc/models.py", line 470, in save
    super(MODEL_A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in <listcomp>
    values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1396, in pre_save
    value = timezone.now()
TypeError: '_SentinelObject' object is not callable
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning objects which don't support `copy.deepcopy()` during `setUpTestData()` is deprecated. Either assign the unit attribute during `setUpClass()` or `setUp()`, or add support for `deepcopy()`.

So there might be a code in your test cases like below:

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    super(YourTestClassNameHere, cls).setUpTestData()
```

Change this code as follows:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(YourTestClassNameHere, cls).setUpClass()
```

This will resolve your `_SentinelObject` issues.